# Expand inner CSS grid that is inside parent CSS grid

Tags: css

How do I expand the inner most grid to take up more space to the right. I want it to be the same width from its left side. There is a big gap to the right of the inner most div. The entire project can be see at this codepen: https://codepen.io/centem/pen/oNvZLgP?editors=1100

CSS

```
.inner-header {
    background-color: #96ceb4;  
}

.header :nth-child(2) {
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.inner-menu {
    background-color: #ff6f69;
}

.inner-content {
    background-color: #ffcc5c;
}

.inner-footer {
    background-color: #88d8b0;
}

.inner-grid-page > div {
    color: #ffeead;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.inner-grid-page {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 20px 150px 20px;
}

.inner-header {
  grid-column: span 12;
  display: flex;
}

.inner-header > div:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.inner-menu {
    grid-column: span 2;
}

.inner-content {
    grid-column: span 10;
}

.inner-footer {
    grid-column: span 12;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just add `width: 100%` -:

```
.inner-grid-page {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 20px 150px 20px;
}
```

Comment: i just delete my when i see your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For item inside flex, if you want it to take up space set `flex-grow: 1` or `flex: 1`

```
.inner-grid-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 20px 150px 20px;
  flex: 1;
}
```